# mocha failing function in express 4 but not in express 3

Tags: express, mocha.js

ok, I worked through Mr. Keig's book Advanced Express Web App Dev.  In his book, he used Express version 3 to build the API.  I got everything to work in his book on that version.  But when I take his development method and apply it to Express version 4, mocha fails for the heartbeat check saying that it expected a Content Type response of json but received 'text/html'. Is there something that I am missing in Express version 4?

I tried changing the app.get to a app.use, but that did not help.

code at my github (https://github.com/EnergeticPixels/course-api.git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.  naming convention issue.  I had 'heartbeat' as name of route, but I needed '/heartbeat'. Now it works. Except now I get a 'deprecated' warning about res.json.  that is easy fix.